# Custom Push Server Setup

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, push-notification, rabbitmq, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm researching about building a custom server for sending push notifications to clients Webapps (No android or iOS phones). What would be a reliable and scalable stack for building this service? Preferably using a microservice architecture. Thanks.

P.S. I already tried third party services such as FCM, OneSignal, but most of them don't offer a custom domain option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for a current answer (April 2021), you cannot use your own push service because it is tightly coupled with each browser push API implementation:

> But notice that we can't push notifications from our server directly to the user's browser. Instead, only certain servers that browser development companies (like Google, Mozilla, etc.) specifically choose will be able to push notifications to a given browser.

Link:https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **spring-boot** framework for this, which provides easy configuration to connect with firebase using firebase SDK or API's.

1. Download firebase admin SDK : https://console.firebase.google.com/
2. Create spring boot application : https://start.spring.io/
3. Use private key JSON file to connect with firebase using SDK.
4. Expose REST end points to send FCM notifications.

Comment: Thanks, already tried that, but my goal is to send the PNs without FCM or other vendors.